# jquery-chosen plugin - display 'X' on selected item

Tags: javascript, jquery, listbox, jquery-chosen

I am using the jquery-chosen plugin.  It is a multiple selection ListBox.  It is working fine.  But I would like the selected items to have an 'X' beside the item so the user can delete it if they want to.  The default action is to backspace.
What Attribute includes the 'X' on each selected item?
This is my jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $(".chosen-select").chosen({
             search_contains: true,
             no_results_text: "Sorry, no match!",
             single_backstroke_delete: false,
             allow_single_deselect: true
         });
         $('.chosen-container').css('width', '600px');
    });
```

This is my ListBox code:

```
 <asp:ListBox ID="lstBoxTo" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple"
                    data-placeholder="Choose recipient(s)…" class="chosen-select">                       
        </asp:ListBox>
```

Currently, I am using the attribute, 'single-backstroke-delete' but I would like to have an 'X' beside the selected value instead.
How do you configure that?

THanks.

**UPDATE**
I believe my problem is the .png file needs to be added, 'chosen-sprite.png' to the project.  The chosen.css references it.  I added it to my Images folder and changed all of the paths to 'Image/chosen-sprite.png' but it still does not work.
THere is a comment at the top of the .css file not to 'hand edit the file'.
Does anyone know how to add the image file to the project so it can see it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added the chosen-sprite.png to the folder that had the chose.css file and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the documentation [here](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html), it looks as if you need to add the `multiple` attribute to your `asp:ListBox`.

```
 <asp:ListBox ID="lstBoxTo" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple"         
    multiple data-placeholder="Choose recipient(s)…" 
    class="chosen-select">                       
 </asp:ListBox>
```

If ASP.Net objects to having an attribute (`multiple`) with no value, you could try `multiple="true"` and see if that works.

Disclaimer:  this is all from reading the documentation.  I have not tried this myself.

Comment: That did not work.  From the documentation, it seems that 'multiple' will determine if the listbox is single selection or multiple.  That is not what I need.  When the selections are displayed in the listbox, if the user wants to delete one, the default action is to backspace.  To me, that is not intuitive enough. I would like each selected item in the list box to have an 'X' beside it to indicate if you want to delete it, click the 'x'.  The example shown on the Chosen website shows the items this way.  I have read the documents and don't see how to get there.